# Where to start? Sequence of functions.

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I've been playing around with composing translations with the modulus function.

Let $f_0(x) = |x|$, and $f_{n+1}(x) = \left| f_n(x)-\frac{1}{n+1}\right|$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

**I would like to understand $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n}$, but I have no idea where to start.**

The graphs $y=f_k(x)$ start to look like fractals, even for small $k$. Here are the graphs for $4 \le k \le 7$. The final picture is $y=f_{20}(x)$, but the line in too thick to show the detail.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The largest and smallest zeros are at $\pm(1+1/2+..+1/n)$ which diverges. Inside this interval the maximum $M_n$ of $f_n$ satisfies $M_0=0$, $M_n=\max(1/(n+1),M_{n-1}-1/(n+1))$. From this it follows that $M_n=1/(n+1)$. Therefore $f_n\to0$ pointwise.

Comment: @arts Thank you very much for your comment. Please would you consider posting an Answer, and giving more details? Any references you could give for such techniques would equally be apprenticed. Thanks again.

Comment: The only general technique I used was to compute the maximum of each function (inside the interval where it make sense to compute it) and show that that maximum tends to zero. Since the functions are non-negative, the limit is zero. Because of the way the functions are defined the maximum of the next element is either the previous maximum decreased by $1/(n+1)$ or $1/(n+1)$. Maybe the other general thing is the use of induction to solve prove that $M_n=1/(n+1)$. Otherwise, it is a rather trivial exercise.

Comment: For any $y\geq 0$ and any $m\in \Bbb N$ the sequence $(y-\sum_{j=1}^n(m+j)^{-1})_{n\in \Bbb N}$ tends to $-\infty$ as $n\to \infty.$ .... So for a fixed $x$ let $m(1)$ be the least $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $|x|<\sum_{j=1}^n(j+1)^{-1}.$  Then for $k\in \Bbb N$ let $m(k+1)$ be the least $n>m(k)$ such that $f_{m(k)}<\sum_{j= 2+m(k)}^n(j+1)^{-1}.$.....  Now if $m(1)<m$ there exists $k \in  \Bbb N$ with $m(k)<m\leq m(k+1), $ and $ |f_m(x)|<(m(k)+1)^{-1}.$